# No head section when requesting page via YQL API

Tags: proxy, yql, head

I'm trying to get the full page via yahoo YQL API, in order to access metadata fields defined in the target page `head` section (specifically open graph metadata).

My example URL:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http://www.google.com%22&format=xml
```

But it does not contain any metadata parameters...is there another way to call this Yahoo API to include the head section or perhaps a similar service that does include the `head` section?

Comment: You cannot use YQL to parse google.com directly, use the Community Tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You cannot use YQL to parse google.com directly, use the Community
>   Tables

Here's an example to get the meta tags of http://php.net/explode via YQL.

```
SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = 'http://php.net/explode' AND xpath='descendant-or-self::meta'
```

Partial Query Output:

```
    <results>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
    </results>
```

Comment: You code works, thanks. Though I do not understand your comment 'You cannot use YQL to parse google.com directly, use the Community Tables'? What does that mean and why is Google excluded from usage with YQL?

Comment: YQL respect the robots.txt directives and google doesn't allow YQL to parse it.

Comment: on [YQL Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/), check Show Community Tables on the upper left side to enable the Community Tables, google is included.

Comment: Ah I see. And what would be the directive in the robots.txt? I don't see YQL in Google's robots.txt?

Comment: I now see that this does return results btw: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27%20AND%20xpath=%27descendant-or-self::meta%27&format=xml

Comment: The link I posted returns the google.com metadata, maybe you mean the Google.com search results pages?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about search results, I've tried before and it didn't work.